# Insert LineFeed instead of CRLF

Tags: c#

Using StringBuilder and in my string I am using Environment.NewLine, when I open it it shows as CRLF, Is there another commands in C# that the output shows as "LF" only and not "CRLF"?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Simply write

```
sb.Append((char)10);
```

or more readable

```
sb.Append('\n');
```

even more readable

```
const char LF = '\n';
sb.Append(LF);
```

Answer (score 16):

The `Environment.NewLine` exists solely to differ between Windows-like line endings (`\r\n`) and  Unix-style line endings (`\n`), so when writing text files and the like you don't have to bother which one to use (imagine you're running on Mono on Linux, then you want just `\n`, which the `Environment. NewLine` will contain as it is set by the runtime).

So when you know you always and only want a line feed character, simply put `\n` in your code. It won't change.

Comment: Well, Windows uses CRLF, Mac only CR, all other Unixe only LF.

Comment: Except [when this answer was written (2012)](https://superuser.com/questions/439440/did-mac-os-lion-switch-to-using-line-feeds-lf-n-for-line-breaks-instead-of), that was already a relict of the past (pre-Mac OS X, from **2001**). So no, I don't think this answer needs that update in 2023.

Answer (score 6):

Use escaped character '\n' instead of Environment.Newline

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx for escaped characters list and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx for Environment.Newline behavior.

Comment: Why? This seems like a TERRIBLE idea. My french is a little rusty, but I saw nothing in the MSDN link you provided that provides justification for bypassing a language feature that simplifies appending correct line feeds across multiple platforms.

Comment: @RogerHill The reason is that this answers the original posters question, which is how to append a LINE-FEED character specifically, instead of the system default newline sequence.